# How can I plot hourly averaged time series grouped by month?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a long term time series (22 years), and want to group the data by month and average each hour to get a diurnal temperature profile. Below is my data set.

```
        Datetime.LST ruc.197.118 narr.225.118 KLAF VAIv212_08748740771
1   12/31/1996 18:00          NA      -0.7843   NA                  NA
2   12/31/1996 19:00          NA      -1.2432   NA                  NA
3   12/31/1996 20:00          NA      -1.7022   NA                  NA
4   12/31/1996 21:00          NA      -2.1611   NA                  NA
5   12/31/1996 22:00          NA      -2.1026   NA                  NA
6   12/31/1996 23:00          NA      -2.0440   NA                  NA
7      1/1/1997 0:00          NA      -1.9854   NA           0.4120480
8      1/1/1997 1:00          NA      -1.7506   NA           0.4400940
9      1/1/1997 2:00          NA      -1.5157   NA           0.4594420
10     1/1/1997 3:00          NA      -1.2808   NA           0.3232730
11     1/1/1997 4:00          NA      -0.9326   NA           0.0754700
12     1/1/1997 5:00          NA      -0.5844   NA          -0.0730896
13     1/1/1997 6:00          NA      -0.2363   NA          -0.1574400
14     1/1/1997 7:00          NA       0.3422   NA          -0.2461240
15     1/1/1997 8:00          NA       0.9207   NA          -0.0277405
```

```
  temperature_data <- read.csv(temp_hourly, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  monthly_hourly <- temperature_data %>%
              dmy_hm(.$Datetime.LST, tz = "GMT") %>%
              dplyr::group_by(month=format(Datetime.LST,'%m'), hour=format(as.POSIXct(cut(Datetime.LST, breaks = 'hour')),"%H")) %>%
              summarise(meanVal=mean(val,na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

Example dataset using `dput`

```
> dput(head(temperature_data[, c(1,2,3,4,5)]))
structure(list(Datetime.LST = c("12/31/1996 18:00", "12/31/1996 19:00", 
"12/31/1996 20:00", "12/31/1996 21:00", "12/31/1996 22:00", "12/31/1996 23:00"
), ruc.197.118 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), narr.225.118 = c(-0.7843, -1.2432, -1.7022, -2.1611, 
-2.1026, -2.044), KLAF = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), VAIv212_08748740771 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("Datetime.LST", 
"ruc.197.118", "narr.225.118", "KLAF", "VAIv212_08748740771"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Datetime.LST is brought in as `ch` data type. I have had some issues getting different date packages(`lubridate`) to agree with `dplyr`'s `group_by` function.

Attached is an example plot output that I would like to see.
[image: Monthly_Diurnal_Temperature_Profiles]

With using Andrews comments below, updated code and current output:

```
  temperature_data <- read.csv(temp_hourly, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  monthly_hourly <-   temperature_data %>%
    mutate(Datetime.LST = mdy_hm(Datetime.LST, tz = "GMT"),
           day = day(Datetime.LST),
           month = month(Datetime.LST),
           hour = hour(Datetime.LST)) %>%
    group_by(month, hour) %>% 
    summarise(
      ruc.197.118 = mean(ruc.197.118, na.rm = TRUE),
      narr.225.118 = mean(narr.225.118, na.rm = TRUE),
      KLAF = mean(KLAF, na.rm = TRUE),
      VAIv212_08748740771 = mean(VAIv212_08748740771, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) %>%
    # next step creates a dummy year to group month/day/hr as datetime
    mutate(month_name = month(month, label = TRUE)) 
  ggplot(data = monthly_hourly,aes(x = hour)) +
  geom_line(color = "red", aes(y = ruc.197.118)) + 
  geom_line(color = "blue", aes(y = narr.225.118)) + 
  geom_line(color = "black", aes(y = KLAF)) + 
  geom_line(color = "orange", aes(y = VAIv212_08748740771)) + 
  xlab("Temperature degC") +
  ylab("Hour of Day") +
  facet_wrap(~ month_name)
```

[image: newoutput.]

Comment: Hey there, would be helpful to have a couple of extra things to see what has been done and what can be done. Can you post some of the code you've tried (using `group_by`) and a sample of your data (using `dput`) to be sure solutions posted work on your data specifically?

Comment: (as an initial thing to try, `lubridate`'s `month()` function will extract the month from a date/time variable, which you could then use as a new variable to group by (`df %>% mutate(month = month(Datetime.LST) %>% group_by(month)`...), if your `Datetime.LST` is formatted already?

Comment: @AndrewBaxter pushed some edits forward.

Comment: Hi @twseewx, are there additional problems you're still looking to resolve from this? Please do detail if things aren't working, or mark the question as answered if all is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from your code above, it would work to extract date, month and hour as new variables, then group, summarise and graph:

```r
monthly_hourly <- df %>%
  bind_rows(data.frame(Datetime.LST = "1/1/1970 1:00")) %>% 
  mutate(Datetime.LST = mdy_hm(Datetime.LST, tz = "GMT"),
         day = day(Datetime.LST),
         month = month(Datetime.LST, label = TRUE),
         hour = hour(Datetime.LST)) %>%
  group_by(month, hour) %>% 
  summarise(
    ruc.197.118 = mean(ruc.197.118, na.rm = TRUE),
    narr.225.118 = mean(narr.225.118, na.rm = TRUE),
    KLAF = mean(KLAF, na.rm = TRUE),
    VAIv212_08748740771 = mean(VAIv212_08748740771, na.rm = TRUE)
  )

monthly_hourly %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hour)) +
  geom_line(color = "red", aes(y = ruc.197.118)) + 
  geom_line(color = "blue", aes(y = narr.225.118)) + 
  geom_line(color = "black", aes(y = KLAF)) + 
  geom_line(color = "orange", aes(y = VAIv212_08748740771)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ month, scales = "free")
```

Comment: @twseewx - had noticed your coded added there as well, will update answer shortly to not reinvent the wheel!

Comment: So i have it working with date month hour set up, so couldn't i just use dplyr `filter` to pick out month 1 and then get the mean for each hour as well?

Comment: ah I see what you mean! hadn't clocked that you'd meant to group all Januaries together (across 22 years) etc. One way could be to `filter` and create a new dataframe for each month. But this would require you to do it 12 times then bring 12 dataframes back together. A better principle is to keep all together in one dataframe - I've adjusted code above to `group_by` month/day/hour, then plot grouped by month (now displayed as character name). Does that help?

Comment: I do not have the updated version of `dplyr` for `summarise_if` to be used, and cannot updated as far as I'm concerned in my environment.

Comment: it's a shortcut for individualised `summarise` calls - see edits for the four lines averaging the relevant variables

Comment: oh okay that makes more intuitive sense to me now. Everything works up to 
```mutate(datetime = ymd_hm(paste0("00", month, day, " ", hour, ":00")),
           month_name = month(month, label = TRUE))```

when applying that i get ```There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> monthly_hourly
Source: local data frame [8,784 x 9]
Groups: month, day

Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , !too_wide, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Comment: I did get it to plot by removing the pipes after `mutate(monthly...` However the plots are quite wonky, with what looks like multiple values for each hour of the day. I'll dive into it a bit more and figure it out. appreciate all of that help though thus far!

Comment: have updated my code to match your pattern of assigning to `monthly_hourly` with some small tweaks (`scales = 'free'` to suit your data, and piping the `monthly_hourly` dataframe in). These might have been causing some of the confusion?

Comment: I've updated my code above now to incorporate the edits you provided and also my minor tweaks. with an updated output plot.